# ANSYS Fluent: Defining External Force on a Cell Zone

Tags: simulation, fluid-dynamics, ansys-fluent

I am using ANSYS Fluent 15 to simulate a case of fluid flow. In my case, I have three cell zones in my simulation, let's call them top, middle and bottom.

My requirement is to put a vertical constant force in the "middle" cell zone. I can not use gravity because it is then acted in all other cell zones as well. **My purpose is to define this force exclusively in the middle cell zone only.**
Apart from it, I tried to use the "Y-momentum" source term in cell zone conditions panel but it a did not seem to work either.

Any suggestion or help would be great. Thanks

Comment: This question if off-topic. It is too specific to Ansys Fluent, and it would be more suitable for Ansys forums. I haven't used Fluent before, but I have read in the documentation that you can define force terms using [UDF](http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~barbertj/CFD%20Training/Fluent/7%20User%20Defined%20Functions.pdf)(User Defined Functions) that are programmed in C.